# How to make an image work inside a function in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey i have an image inside a function that is not appearing where it should be. The image is saved in the same folder as the code. After looking at solutions I found that i had to make the image a global variable for it to work. I did this and after it didnt work again, i tried making some other variables global as i wasnt sure if i did it to the right one.

Im also wondering if the problem could be that the geometry isnt working due to it being in a function

Heres what it should look like (the top left home button, the home icon is the image)
[image: Heres what it should look like]
And heres how its turning out when inside a function
[image: Heres what it looks like when ran inside the function]

Heres the function if you would like to look at it

```
from tkinter import *

def resourcePage():
    global homeIcon
    global file

    resource = Tk()
    resource.title("Resource Page")
    resource.resizable(0, 0)

    header = LabelFrame(resource, bg="white")
    content = LabelFrame(resource, bg="white")

    header.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Forces column to expand to fill all available space
    homeButton = Button(content, width=50, height=50)
    try:
        homeIcon = PhotoImage(file="yes.png")
        homeButton.config(image=homeIcon)
        homeButton.image = homeIcon
    except TclError:
        print("Home")
    homeButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=2, pady=2)

    # each section of code below is for their respective labels on the page
    papersLabel = Label(content, text="Exam Papers", bg="#12a8e3", fg="white", font=("Ariel", 26, "bold"),
                        activebackground="#12a8e3", anchor="w", padx=15)
    papersLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=15, pady=(15, 5), ipadx=429, ipady=10)
    papersPhysics = Label(content, text="Physics:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    papersPhysics.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    papersHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    papersHyperlinks.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)
    papersCS = Label(content, text="Computer Science:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    papersCS.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    papersHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    papersHyperlinks.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)

    questionsLabel = Label(content, text="Practice Exam Questions:", bg="#12a8e3", fg="white",
                           font=("Ariel", 26, "bold"), activebackground="#12a8e3", anchor="w", padx=15)
    questionsLabel.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=15, pady=(25, 5), ipadx=328, ipady=10)
    questionsPhysics = Label(content, text="Physics:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    questionsPhysics.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    questionsHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    questionsHyperlinks.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)
    questionsCS = Label(content, text="Computer Science:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    questionsCS.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    questionsHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    questionsHyperlinks.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)

    videosLabel = Label(content, text="Helpful Videos:", bg="#12a8e3", fg="white", font=("Ariel", 26, "bold"),
                        activebackground="#12a8e3", anchor="w", padx=15)
    videosLabel.grid(row=12, column=0, padx=15, pady=(25, 5), ipadx=415, ipady=10)
    videosPhysics = Label(content, text="Physics:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    videosPhysics.grid(row=13, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    videosHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    videosHyperlinks.grid(row=14, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)
    videosCS = Label(content, text="Computer Science:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    videosCS.grid(row=15, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    videosHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    videosHyperlinks.grid(row=16, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24,
                          pady=(0, 25))  # y padding here to keep some space from the bottom of the page

    header.grid(row=0, sticky='NSEW')
    content.grid(row=1, sticky='NSEW')
```

Comment: did u try using Image class of `PIL`? to open the image and then use it in the button?

Comment: Is the error message "Home" being printed? Instead of just ignoring all tcl errors, have you tried printing out the error?

Comment: Did you have another instance of `Tk()` in the main block?

Comment: @CoolCloud how would i do this?

Comment: @acw1668 yeah in the main block theres another page. Is this a problem?

Comment: @BryanOakley the home is not being printed. And how would printing out the error help? Im not 100% sure on how this tcl error thing works

Comment: Then try changing `Tk()` to `Toplevel()` inside `resourcePage()`.

Comment: How would printing out the error help? It might tell you that the file doesn't exist or the data is in the wrong format or several other specific things.

Comment: If you have a second instance of `Tk`, that would explain the problem. Plesae provide us a _complete_ [mcve].

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for the help it was the fact that there was a second instance of tk. I changed tk to toplevel() as suggested and everything is looking how it should. Im not sure what tk and toplevel does that effects this

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks it was that there was a second instance of tk

Comment: Your example code only has a single instance of `Tk`. This is why we request a _complete_ example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, messages from when the `TclError` exception is raised are being suppressed.

Try to change the `except` clause

```py
except TclError as Error:
        print(Error)
```

For me running your code, it seems `yes.png` can't be found in the working directory of the Python process running your script because I keep getting

```
couldn't open "yes.png": no such file or directory
```

### EDIT

Obtained result by using a placeholder `test.png` :

[image: result of running the modified script]

### Modified script

```py
from tkinter import *

def resourcePage():
    global homeIcon
    global file

    resource = Tk()
    resource.title("Resource Page")
    resource.resizable(0, 0)

    header = LabelFrame(resource, bg="white")
    content = LabelFrame(resource, bg="white")

    header.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Forces column to expand to fill all available space
    homeButton = Button(content, width=50, height=50)
    try:
        #Modification 1:
            # Either provide a full or relative path or
            # change the working directory by import os; os.chdir()
        homeIcon = PhotoImage(file="X:/SomeFolder/yes.png")
        homeButton.config(image=homeIcon)
        homeButton.image = homeIcon
        #Modification 2:
    except TclError as Error:
        print(Error)
    homeButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=2, pady=2)

    # each section of code below is for their respective labels on the page
    papersLabel = Label(content, text="Exam Papers", bg="#12a8e3", fg="white", font=("Ariel", 26, "bold"),
                        activebackground="#12a8e3", anchor="w", padx=15)
    papersLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=15, pady=(15, 5), ipadx=429, ipady=10)
    papersPhysics = Label(content, text="Physics:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    papersPhysics.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    papersHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    papersHyperlinks.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)
    papersCS = Label(content, text="Computer Science:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    papersCS.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    papersHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    papersHyperlinks.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)

    questionsLabel = Label(content, text="Practice Exam Questions:", bg="#12a8e3", fg="white",
                           font=("Ariel", 26, "bold"), activebackground="#12a8e3", anchor="w", padx=15)
    questionsLabel.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=15, pady=(25, 5), ipadx=328, ipady=10)
    questionsPhysics = Label(content, text="Physics:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    questionsPhysics.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    questionsHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    questionsHyperlinks.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)
    questionsCS = Label(content, text="Computer Science:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    questionsCS.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    questionsHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    questionsHyperlinks.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)

    videosLabel = Label(content, text="Helpful Videos:", bg="#12a8e3", fg="white", font=("Ariel", 26, "bold"),
                        activebackground="#12a8e3", anchor="w", padx=15)
    videosLabel.grid(row=12, column=0, padx=15, pady=(25, 5), ipadx=415, ipady=10)
    videosPhysics = Label(content, text="Physics:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    videosPhysics.grid(row=13, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    videosHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    videosHyperlinks.grid(row=14, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)
    videosCS = Label(content, text="Computer Science:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    videosCS.grid(row=15, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    videosHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    videosHyperlinks.grid(row=16, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24,
                          pady=(0, 25))  # y padding here to keep some space from the bottom of the page

    header.grid(row=0, sticky='NSEW')
    content.grid(row=1, sticky='NSEW')

    #Modification 3
    resource.mainloop()
resourcePage()
```

Comment: wouldnt tht be because you dont have such file in your directory?

Comment: tested it with a placeholder/dummy `yes.png`, it worked

Comment: thanks i tried this and it doesnt seem to have any effect on the look

Comment: @Space no error message, just that nothing changed. The box was still not the right size